# SQL соединение нескольких таблиц в одном запросе

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Собственно имею запрос для 1ой таблицы:

```
$db_referal = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * from movies WHERE movies_name LIKE 
'%$referal%' ORDER BY movies_name LIMIT 11")
```

И нужно чтобы в этом же query ещё выполнялось например:

```
("SELECT * from user WHERE username LIKE 'тот же %$referal%' ORDER BY username LIMIT 11")
```

Подскажите, как это правильно соединить, я уже много перепробовал. Суть в том, чтобы в всплывающем окошке высвечивались не только найденные видео, но и пользователи(даже те которые не залили ни 1 видео).

Comment: Если вам просто список названий/имен нужен, сделайте union

Comment: А как это правильно записать? Мне нужны высвечивать имена видео и клиентов, которые впишет пользователь в своем referal

Comment: query("SELECT * from movies WHERE movies_name LIKE '%$referal%' ORDER BY movies_name LIMIT 11)union(SELECT * from user WHERE username LIKE '%$referal%' ORDER BY username LIMIT 11") Так написал, выдало ошибку номер 18

Comment: Да, sql вставленный в php код.

Comment: скобки то откуда у вас там в `)union(`?

Comment: да и перечень полей в `union` Должен быть одинаков, что вряд ли возможно для таблиц `Movies` и `users` при выборе `*`

Comment: Да, вот поэтому не знаю, как это делается, нужны разные таблицы, разные поля, а запрос один и тот же =(

Comment: query("SELECT movies_name from movies WHERE movies_name LIKE '%$referal%' ORDER BY movies_name LIMIT 11) union (SELECT username  from user WHERE username LIKE '%$referal%' ORDER BY username LIMIT 11") -надо одинаковое число полей одинакового типа

Comment: Дык было уже, ошибку номер 18 возвращает.

Comment: @teran скобки особо роли не играют

Comment: сделайте двумя запросами и не парьтесь. а то потом понадобится пользователей показать чуть по другому, как то выделить, ссылки сделать, придется учиться различать строки фильмов и пользователей, возвращаемых вместе. И номер ошибки который вы приводите никому ничего не скажет, потому что вы даже СУБД не указали. А синтаксис у разных СУБД немного разный и номера ошибок - тем более. лучше бы сообщение об ошибке дали, там наверняка точно сообщается, что не так

Comment: @Mike mySql СУБД, нету там сообщения. Двумя запросами AJAX выйдет асинхронно, я в этом деле слаб, и получится, что раз будут появляться пользователи,а раз видео. Все-таки хотелось бы вместе реализовать, как на Ютубе поиск.

Comment: Значит вы не выводите сообщение http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php А вообще, любой запрос надо отлаживать в mysql (или в более удобной среде, вроде mysql workbench), а уже потом переносить в php. И никакой зависимости между количеством запросов от клиента и кол-вом запросов в БД нет. вы можете запросто при обработке одного запроса из браузера, сначала циклом прочитать данные из первого запроса, потом из второго и отдать все вместе клиенту

Comment: А вообще у вас явно что то со скобками. В начале запроса скобка не открывается, но при этом перед union она почему то закрывается. после union скобка открывается, но больше не закрывается. Ну и * выбирать конечно нельзя, явно перечислите нужные поля и следите за тем, что бы количество полей в двух частях совпадало